# How to pass the date and time from one layout to another

Tags: java, android

First layout has a button to pick date,another button to pick time. After picking date & time  from popups, a next button is clicked. On this click , the second layout that contains date and time picker. In this we have to set the previously fetched date and time...

Comment: "One layout to other layout  using date & time picker." What is this ? You want to pass date and time to another activity ?

Comment: questions with less than 100 words should be forbidden.

Comment: First layout has a button to pick date,another button to pick time. After picking from popups, a next button is clicked. On this click , the second layout that contains date and time picker. In this we have to set the previously fetched date and time...

Comment: Better you can show and get the date and time from the single AlertDialog....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pick the date and store into the string same way store the time now if you press next button and open the another activity you can pass this date and time value using Intent object by put().

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,YourClass.class);
intent.put("Date",date);
intent.put("Time",time);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in another activity you can get this way

```
String date = getIntent().getExtra().getString("Date");
String time = getIntent().getExtra().getString("Time");
```

if you want to set the date and time value in same activity then no need you can use this date and time object in your activity class and declare as

```
private String date,time;
```

so you can you only within this acitivity.